# Laravel hasMany() based on 2 conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a User model and a Booking model. A User has many Bookings. The bookings migration has the following structure:

- **a) `first_user_id`** being the user who **initiated** the booking and
- **b) the `second_user_id`** being who the first user **booked with**

When adding this relationship, however, any saved bookings only show up for the `first_user_id` who initiated it. No bookings appear for the second user.

In `User.php` I've got:

```
public function hasBookings() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Booking', 'first_user_id', 'user_auth_id');
}
```

Is there a way I can do a where clause on this relationship so that bookings attach if the 'user_auth_id' matches `first_user_id` OR `second_user_id`?

Comment: 1) I would make these 2 distinct relationships and check for either or,  2) `hasBookings` is a bit misleading as a relationship method name, personally I'd expect that to return a boolean value, not a relationship

Comment: `A User has many Bookings` and from your code it seems, many users are related to a booking, then you can make it many to many with some extra field. another way will be make 2 relationship based on type of relationship or even using scope.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu manyToMany is a good shout, I didn't think of that. I'm still not sure how I could achieve retrieving all bookings to display under the user model though.I've tried a many to many relationship with a pivot table but I get the same results - the user that didn't initiate the booking has no bookings under its model. Could you expand on your comment and give a brief example?

Comment: @Nats you can use extra field in pivot table where you can add a flag to handle it.

Comment: Thanks @PrafullaKumarSahu - in the end I created a pivot table and set a relationship on User and Booking with the pivot model. I'm getting the expected result now.

Comment: @Nats glad to know your issue is resolved.

Comment: @Nats you can post your answer and mark it correct, so that it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I created a pivot table with information on the booking and the user, and then set a relationship in the user model with that pivot table:

- Create a pivot table with foreign keys to both booking and the user tables:

```
Schema::create('booking_users_profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_auth_id')->on('users_profile')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('booking_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('booking_id')->references('id')->on('bookings')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

- Then in the user model:

```
public function bookings() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\BookingUsersProfile', 'user_id', 'user_auth_id');
    }
```

Whenever I create an entry in the booking table now, I make two entries in the pivot table, one for each user in the session (never more than 2). The relationship in the model above ensures that the bookings field in the user model is populated with those bookings where user_id matches the user's model id.

```
foreach ($filteredBookings as $booking) {

            $newBooking = new Booking();

            $newBooking->start = $booking->startDate;
            $newBooking->end = $booking->endDate;
            $newBooking->confirmed = "N";
            $newBooking->save();

            $newPivotBooking = new BookingUsersProfile();
            $newPivotBooking->user_id = $userId;
            $newPivotBooking->booking_id = $newBooking->id;
            $newPivotBooking->save();


            $newPivotBooking = new BookingUsersProfile();
            $newPivotBooking->user_id = $request->secondUserId;
            $newPivotBooking->booking_id = $newBooking->id;
            $newPivotBooking->save();
        }
```

This solved my issue and gave me the desired outcome:

E.g. user model for user with id = 1

```
"bookings": [
{
"id": 1,
"user_id": 1,
"booking_id": 6,
"created_at": "2020-10-02T11:42:11.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-10-02T11:42:14.000000Z",
}]
```

E.g. user model for user with id = 5

```
"bookings": [
{
"id": 2,
"user_id": 5,
"booking_id": 6,
"created_at": "2020-10-02T11:42:20.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-10-02T11:42:23.000000Z",
}]
```